# SQL Query Performance Rewrite?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Edit: Long Story Short, I am using outsystems service studio, its very much different than C# Visual Web Developer or MVC, so there is a lot of limitations. Please don't mention you should re do your logic, but I pretty much need a query that increases/improve the performance given already working query.

I have two tables, BookTemp which consist of field Id(auto-increment) and Attribute1, example of records are:

```
Id  |  Attribute1
 1  |  123-ABC-12
 2  |  2013-01-02
 3  |  12
 4  |  233-EWT-33
 5  |  2013-01-02
 6  |  24
 7  |  873-DEF-92
 8  |  2013-01-02
 9  |  32
10  |  113-QWE-13
11  |  2013-01-02
12  |  2
```

Then another table, Order, with field item, date, qty

As you can see every 3 record in BookTemp is 1 record of Order

But how do I write a single query that can do that iterate every 3 records in BookTemp

In my code I have a loop that first it insert those 3 records, then delete those 3 records and insert the new top 3 records by id then again and again

Below is my real query that I used, thus the tables aforementioned is different but you shall get the idea...

Hi I am still quite new to sql

Can anyone rewrite this query of mine but have better performance, I know for fact that my query has a lot of select statements and that really slows down by a lot.

```
INSERT INTO order 
            ([item], 
             [co_line], 
             [qty_shipped], 
             [uom], 
             [whse], 
             [price], 
             [co_num], 
             [cust_num], 
             [cust_seq], 
             [order_date], 
             [qty_ordered], 
             [ship_date]) 
SELECT (SELECT TOP 1 [attribute1] 
        FROM   booktemp), 
       (SELECT [attribute1] 
        FROM   booktemp 
        WHERE  [id] = (SELECT TOP 1 [id] 
                       FROM   booktemp) 
                      + 1), 
       (SELECT [attribute1] 
        FROM   booktemp 
        WHERE  [id] = (SELECT TOP 1 [id] 
                       FROM   booktemp) 
                      + 2), 
       (SELECT [attribute1] 
        FROM   booktemp 
        WHERE  [id] = (SELECT TOP 1 [id] 
                       FROM   booktemp) 
                      + 3), 
       (SELECT [attribute1] 
        FROM   booktemp 
        WHERE  [id] = (SELECT TOP 1 [id] 
                       FROM   booktemp) 
                      + 4), 
       (SELECT [attribute1] 
        FROM   booktemp 
        WHERE  [id] = (SELECT TOP 1 [id] 
                       FROM   booktemp) 
                      + 5), 
       (SELECT [attribute1] 
        FROM   booktemp 
        WHERE  [id] = (SELECT TOP 1 [id] 
                       FROM   booktemp) 
                      + 6), 
       (SELECT [attribute1] 
        FROM   booktemp 
        WHERE  [id] = (SELECT TOP 1 [id] 
                       FROM   booktemp) 
                      + 7), 
       (SELECT [attribute1] 
        FROM   booktemp 
        WHERE  [id] = (SELECT TOP 1 [id] 
                       FROM   booktemp) 
                      + 8), 
       (SELECT [attribute1] 
        FROM   booktemp 
        WHERE  [id] = (SELECT TOP 1 [id] 
                       FROM   booktemp) 
                      + 9), 
       (SELECT [attribute1] 
        FROM   booktemp 
        WHERE  [id] = (SELECT TOP 1 [id] 
                       FROM   booktemp) 
                      + 10), 
       (SELECT [attribute1] 
        FROM   booktemp 
        WHERE  [id] = (SELECT TOP 1 [id] 
                       FROM   booktemp) 
                      + 11)
```

Comment: Which database are you using? It looks like SQL Server syntax, but your question is flagged for both Oracle and MySQL. All three databases have very different approaches to top-n queries.

Comment: I don't know what you expect to get when you are using `(SELECT TOP 1 [id] FROM   booktemp)` without any ordering.. this could lead to a different `id` in each one of those sub-queries.

Comment: Long story short, I'm using outsystems' service studio to write my web applications they accept both sql and orcle queries but I mostly use SQL. booktemp has only 2 columns: id and attribute1. I can add order by id

Comment: Is `booktemp` indexed? How long is the query as-is taking? How long do you want it to take?

Comment: I pretty much need a query that doesn't rely on that many select statement that I have there :(

Comment: In addition, I just need to enter first 12 records into the Order Table, and I'll be Deleting those first 12 records that I inserted from booktemp and then iterate inserting the 12 new records again. then until book temp reaches to 0

Answer (score 1):

For me, it's a strange design that you want insert records one by one, not as set. You may want re-think the way you designed for process.

For your questions. You can do it by one query like this (On SQL server)

```
SELECT MAX([col0]) AS [item], 
  MAX([col1]), MAX([col2]), MAX([col3]), MAX([col4]), MAX([col5]), MAX([col6]), MAX([col7]), MAX([col8]), MAX([col9]), MAX([col10]), MAX([col11])
FROM (
    SELECT 
      CAST((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) - 1) /12 AS INT) as group_id,
      'col' + CAST(((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) - 1) % 12) AS VARCHAR(10)) AS col_type,
      id,
      attribute1
    FROM booktemp
) a
PIVOT ( max(attribute1) for col_type in ([col0], [col1],[col2],[col3],[col4],[col5],[col6],[col7],[col8],[col9],[col10],[col11]) ) piv
GROUP BY group_id
```